# Angular 5 and NPM

Tags: angular, npm, angular5

Is it possible to install Angular 5 dependencies(currently in RC stage) using npm?

This command shows no Angular 5 dependencies:

```
npm show @angular/core@* version
```

Or is it possible to download it from repository and install: https://github.com/angular/angular/

Thanks

Comment: you can specify the version in `package.json` and run `npm update`

Comment: Thank you, @QuentinLaillé . It worked. But why 5.x dependency was not shown in npm show command ?

Comment: I have no answer for that unfortunately, I'd be glad to know if you can get an answer :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating Angular 4.x to Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104188/migrating-angular-4-x-to-angular-5)

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: Angular 5 has been released (on Nov 1st 2017) and this is the npm command to upgrade to it (windows syntax):

```
npm install @angular/animations@'^5.0.0' @angular/common@'^5.0.0' @angular/compiler@'^5.0.0' @angular/compiler-cli@'^5.0.0' @angular/core@'^5.0.0' @angular/forms@'^5.0.0' @angular/http@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-browser@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-server@'^5.0.0' @angular/router@'^5.0.0' typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@'^5.5.2'
npm install typescript@2.4.2 --save-exact
```

Also, you can read more about the release here: https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced

And you can find out the upgrade guide here: https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following instruction:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
```

then

```
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
```

and

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

Clean up the cache

(     `npm cache clean -f` ) or ( `npm cache verify` )

Install angular globally

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
local project setup if you have one
rm -rf node_modules

npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

and finally,

```
npm install
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: (As of npm@5, `npm cache verify` or `npm cache clean -f` if you're sure)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Run **npm update** command. 
This will automatically update all the required dependencies and files.
After running the command you can check the version by running **ng -version**