# Migrating Angular 4.x to Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have read the following blogs and documentation

- [Angular Blog](https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced)
- [Alligator IO Docs](https://alligator.io/angular/angular-5/)
- [Official Documentation](https://angular.io/docs)

and no clear information about how to migrate from 4.x to 5.

Tried the following commands

- npm install

  ```
  npm install @angular/{animations,common,compiler,compiler-cli,
              core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,
              platform-server,router}@5.0.0
  ```
- yarn installation

  ```
  yarn add @angular/{animations,common,compiler,compiler-cli,
           core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,
           platform-server,router}@5.0.0
  ```
- Tried the [update guide](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/)

  ```
   npm install @angular/animations@'^5.0.0' @angular/common@'^5.0.0' 
          @angular/compiler@'^5.0.0' @angular/compiler-cli@'^5.0.0' 
          @angular/core@'^5.0.0' @angular/forms@'^5.0.0'
          @angular/http@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-browser@'^5.0.0' 
          @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@'^5.0.0' 
          @angular/platform-server@'^5.0.0' @angular/router@'^5.0.0' 
          typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@'^5.5.2'

   npm install typescript@2.4.2 --save-exact
  ```

Nothing worked fine for me. Please help

Comment: When you say  'nothing works', what do you mean? Were you having any errors? For the command from the update guide, I had the remove all the singles quotes between the package and version: https://github.com/StephenFluin/angular-update-guide/issues/4

Comment: You could also edit your package.json file and then run `npm install`.
`"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.0",`

Comment: There is an upgrade guide by the Angular team available [here](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to update all angular provided packages to their latest versions as follows:

```
npm install typescript@2.4 --save-dev

npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest --save
```

This should do all the necessary. Plus you could also update your angular cli that ships with angular 5 as standard version as follows:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Here is the official blogpost by Angular team : https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/. This update guide will help you to migrate from any version to the latest one.

Comment: worked for me... I have used 

npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest -g --save

Comment: @ForamSangani, the -g parameter will install each of those packages globally and should be removed.

Comment: Its necessary for updating Angular 4 to 5 version?

Comment: @Rijo Not necessary but yes V5 does offer some cool improvements in Build Optimizer & Compiler. Check this: https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced. Its all on you.

Comment: instead of `npm cache clean` use `npm cache verify` instead

Comment: The link is currently down now, not sure what problem with their guide

Comment: @ThoVo it loads for me. Just refresh!

Comment: yeah, I saw it worked, thanks :)

Comment: ..might want to add **@angular/cdk@latest** for later versions as well :)

Comment: also had to `npm i -D @angular/language-service@latest`

Answer (score 5):

[This website](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/) made it very easy for me. Put in your version you're upgrading from, and which one you're upgrading to. My app is simple, so it may depend on the complexity of your app.