# Angular CLI re-install Error during Angular Upgrade from 4.3 to 5

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular5

I was following steps to upgrade from Angular 4.3 to Angular 5. Here:
[Migrating Angular 4.x to Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104188/migrating-angular-4-x-to-angular-5)

The angular update steps all went through smoothly.

The problem came after I uninstalled Angular CLI. And when trying to re-install, I get an unusual Python error that doesn't stop unless I force the task to stop.

[image]

If I run the install command `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` 2 more times however. It finishes without error.

Running ng help works. But ng serve results in the following error: 
 [image]

I actually have the Python at that exact location. **C:\Python27\python.exe** 
And I used to be running Angular CLI without a problem. So the python exe didn't cause an issue before I uninstalled it.

Also I tried searching for this "watchpack" error, and manually installed webpack again. That didn't solve my error.

I tried uninstalling Angular CLI at global/local. And re-install at the global level again, this python error consistently show up. And it's one of those infinite loop errors that does not stop without manual intervention.

Most Python errors I have seen from Angular CLI git-hub is an error/warning that ends.

node v6.10.2

npm  5.0.4

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to install the windows build tools which now contain the python you are missing :

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/56

Comment: Care to comment about the downvote ? I've had this issue before and this was the fix, so I can't do much more about this...