# Migration of Angular 4 project to Angular 5

Tags: angular

1. What are the major differences in Angular 4 and Angular 5?
2. How much effort will be required for migrating Angular 4 project to Angular 5
3. Is there any  official documentation available for migration from Angular 4 to Angular 5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating Angular 4.x to Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104188/migrating-angular-4-x-to-angular-5)

Comment: @sachin
You can review this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104188/migrating-angular-4-x-to-angular-5

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [migration guide](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/) to get a "checklist". It tells you what to do before and after the upgrade.

To summarize it,

1. `template` was deprecated and it is removed. Change them to
   `ng-template`
2. Date, Currency, decimal, percent pipes are deprecated and renamed. If you want to use old versions of them, you have to edit your code.
3. HttpModule is deprecated and will be removed later (still exists in v5). You should change it to HttpClientModule

Answer (score 0):

a)   Build Optimizer: This is a tool which was included in the CLI to help the developers in creating a smaller bundle for the application.  Apart from decreasing the users’ bundle size, the feature also helps in increasing the boot speed of the application for the users.

b)   Compiler Improvements: To enhance faster rebuilds for production and AOT (Ahead of Time) builds, Angular 5 supports incremental compilation.

c) New Router Lifecycle Events:This new feature was added to enable the developers in tracking the cycle of the router, starting from running guards to the completion of activation.

d)   HttpClient: This feature has been recommended for all the application as HTTPClient was highly appreciated. The framework developer are not suggesting anymore, to use the previous @angular/http library. Developers can update the HTTPClient in 3 easy steps:

1.In each module, replace HttpModule with Http Client Module from

```
   @angular/common/http.
```

Inject the HttpClient service
remove any

```
   map(res =>res.json())
```

calls, which are no longer needed.