# How to update Angular version to the latest Version?

Tags: angular

I entered the server into the terminal, and it displays an error, asks for updates
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJVFp.png)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Check this out [How to update Angular Cli to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your angular version to the latest Version.
Here is the answer to your question answered by @Vishal Gupta [How to update Angular version to the latest Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104188/migrating-angular-4-x-to-angular-5/47132265#47132265)

For the Quick review, you can find the code below

```
npm install typescript@2.4 --save-dev
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest --save
```